# Can't make outbound connections from haproxy-exporter docker

Tags: docker, monitoring, haproxy, prometheus

I am using MacOS docker, last version (1.12.6). In particular for docker haproxy-exporter (For Prometheus monitoring of haproxy).

It won't connect with my haproxy. I get timeouts. As a basic test I use Telnet... When I get into the docker and execute a telnet I get:

```
/ # telnet MY_IP_ADDRESS 80
HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host
```

If I do this from my Mac shell, it connects:

```
/ # MacBook-Pro:~ icordoba$ telnet MY_IP_ADDRESS 80
Trying MY_IP_ADDRESS...
Connected to MY_IP_ADDRESS.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

It occurs on some dockers... this one is https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter

Thanks for any idea about what I'm missing...

Comment: let me show please haproxy Dockerfile and what command do you use to start container?

Comment: Thanks. I use the command in the haproxy_exporter docs: docker run -p 9101:9101 prom/haproxy-exporter -haproxy.scrape-uri="http://user:pass@haproxy.example.com/haproxy?stats;csv"

Answer (score 0):

If you use [official haproxy image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/) it listens 80 port, but in your case 9101 port hab been exposed.

Try run haproxy  `docker run -p 80:80 prom/haproxy-exporter -haproxy.scrape-uri="user:pass@haproxy.example.com/haproxy?s‌​tats;csv"`

> `-p 80:80` publish port 80 from the container host to port 80 in the
>   container. Make sure the port you're using is free.

and run `telnet MY_IP_ADDRESS 80`

Comment: Sorry, I think you are considering haproxy and haproxy-exporter the same thing. haproxy is already running, it is my reverse proxy, using the official haproxy image, listening to port 80. I can't start haproxy-exporter (a different thing) binding it to port 80.

Comment: oh, sorry. but telnet trying to connect to port 80 (to haproxy, but not to haproxy-exporter). it is right? Oh do you want connect to haproxy-exporter?